# zip file created but not moving to folder in php

Tags: php

files are being uploaded and added to zip the only problem is to move the zip to desired location.the permission is OK i have moved single file. Now i want to create a zip containing multiple files and then moving that zip to folder.

```
$uploaddir = 'upload/page/';    

    if($_FILES['image_file_holder']['name'] != '')
    {   
        $total = count($_FILES['image_file_holder']['name']);
        echo $total;
        $imagarr = explode(".", "myserver.zip");                        
        $newimgfile = $imagarr[0]."_".mt_rand().'.'.$imagarr[1];
            $zipname = $newimgfile;
        $upload = $uploaddir . $newimgfile;
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
                    //Get the temp file path
             $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['image_file_holder']['name'][$i];

             if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
                  $zip->addFile($tmpFilePath);


             }
        }
        $zip->close();



        echo "moving";

        if(move_uploaded_file($zipname,$upload))
        {
            echo "done";
        }
}
```

Comment: Fix quotes here please. And `move_uploaded_file` moves __uploaded file__. You should use just `rename`.

Comment: rename ?can u explain  ?